# routeProvider to change when there's a hash

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I've been googling about this for the past hour but couldn't find an answer.
I want to change the template when there's a parameter passed in the URL.

I tried using hash to retrieve it by calling `$location.hash` in the controller but I can't figure out how to have the routeProvider detect it, here's my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.projects', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
    templateUrl: 'modules/projects/projects.html',
    controller: 'projectsCtrl'
  });
}])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/projects:project', {
  // $routeProvider.when('/projects#project', { // Tried this and it didn't work as well
    templateUrl: 'modules/projects/single-project.html',
    controller: 'projectsCtrl'
  });
}])


.controller('projectsCtrl',['$scope','portfolioService','$location',
    function($scope,portfolioService,$location){
    $scope.portfolio = portfolioService.portfolio;

    console.info('$location.hash',$location.hash());
    // $scope.currentProject = $location;
}])
```